# VS Code + jsconfig.json: "Cannot find module..." for NPM modules with built-in types

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, type-definition

I have a JavaScript project that I'm editing in Visual Studio Code. I have defined the following *jsconfig.json* file for it:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2020"
    },
    "include": [
        "api/**/*.js",
        "bin/**/*.js",
        "lib/**/*.js",
        "models/**/*.d.ts",
        "models/**/*.js",
        "test/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

As with most projects, this one relies on NPM dependencies. Some of those dependencies have built-in type definitions and some do not. For example, two in this project are `'aws-sdk'`, which comes with its own type definitions, and `'express'`, which does not (but has an externally-supplied type definition thanks to Definitely Typed).

The thing that has me scratching my head is that VS Code's JavaScript Language Server/TypeScript "Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'" (as in the example below), but there are no such complaints about `'express'`.

```js
const express = require('express')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk') // Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? ts(2792)
```

This is consistent across the entire codebase--dependencies that have their own type definitions are NOT found by VS Code while dependencies that have externally supplied type definitions (whether added explicitly as dependencies, e.g. `yarn add -D @types/express`, or as automatically acquired types by VS Code) are found just fine by VS Code.

Is there a jsconfig.json setting that I need to investigate to tell VS Code to look inside dependencies for their types (*node_modules/***) in addition to those found in *node_modules/@types*?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?